# Deltron W127G Transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer

Hey I have Recently Purchased A Deltron W127G Open-frame Power supply, but I am confused on how the transformer works. And Since I do not want to blow the thing up I figured Id ask first. The Transformer Can be used on 120V and 240V Here is a Picture of the Transformer. I currently have 1 and 2 jumped together and 3 and 4 jumped together. Is this Correct did I understand the diagram correctly? If so Would I connect mains to 1 and 3?   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the label, if you want to use it with a 120 volt source, you connect terminal 1 to terminal 2, and terminal 3 to terminal 4, then connect the incomming lines to terminal 1 and terminal 4 (but since 3 and 4 are connected, you could connect one side of the line to either 3 or 4.)

Comment: Thank you :) I Just wanted to make sure before I plugged it in these things arent Cheap :p

Answer (score 1):

Peter has given you a good answer for 120VAC in, I'll just throw in the primary side schematic here in case you want to understand it better:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feVtSt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It could have been made a bit simpler by using just one winding with many taps but the series or parallel method reduces material cost and weight.